# How to use JavaScript return value withinHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function:

```
func()
```

which returns text e.g.:

```
Text of First td
```

and I would like to use it like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><script>func()</script></td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, the first `td` is not populated.

How can I do this without using JQuery etc. within that script tag.

**EDIT:**

Another example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><script>decodeURI("st%C3%A5le")</script></td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am generating the `td`s within a loop of an `XSL`. So, I should get the current element instead of `getElementById` or similar.

Comment: can you show us the javascript code? You will probably have to use `document.write` for HTML output

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be to manipulate the element's innerHTML via javascript like so

```js
function showText() {
  document.getElementById('displayArea').innerHTML = "This is some content!";
}

//This will run on page load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  showText();
});
```

```html
<div id="displayArea"></div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

```
function func() {
    document.write('Text of First id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using your existing code via two variations:

```
function func()
{
    return "text of first td";
} 

<td><script>document.write(func())</script></td>
```

variation for the question edit:

```
<td><script>document.write(decodeURI("st%C3%A5le"))</script></td>
```

or by changing func

```
function func()
{
    return document.write("text of first td");
} 

<td><script>func();</script></td>
```

`document.write` executes as soon as it's hit and outputs directly to the document.

Comment: When I use `document.write` it writes its content to whole page. I mean a new page is loaded with just a text that I've used at `document.write` ?

Comment: @kamaci when exactly are you using `document.write`?  In the browser console?  From an event?  It executes immediately but if you call it outside the page-rendering process, then yes, it wipes the content first.

Comment: I call it within an XSL

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind keeping the script tag in the DOM you can use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). That will insert the text immediately after the script tag (inside the `<td>`). If you want to replace the current [ScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) with a [TextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), you can do that like this:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var script = (document.currentScript || function () { 
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
        return scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
    }() );

    script.parentNode.replaceChild( document.createTextNode( func() ), script );
})();
</script>
```

This will completely remove the script from the DOM, and replace it with the text, so that if you inspect the DOM after this you will see only the text inside the `td`, but no script.

[JSFiddle Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/kj1LvwqL/)

I would recommended putting all of that logic inside a function itself, so that your HTML code is cleaner:

```
function func () {  replaceScript( 'Hello!' ); }

var replaceScript = function ( message ) {
    var script = document.currentScript || function () { 
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
        return scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
    }();


   script.parentNode.replaceChild( document.createTextNode( message ), script );
};
```

Then your HTML could look like:

```
<td><script> func() </script></td>
```

or:

```
<td><script> replaceScript( decodeURI("st%C3%A5le") ); </script></td>
```

[JSFiddle Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/kj1LvwqL/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Get a reference to the element and adjust it's innerHTML in your script.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  document.querySelector('td').innerHTML = func();
</script>
```